# Showing a summary of checked items in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox, adobe, acrobat

I'm a noob so bear with me please.

I'm creating a presentation that has 8 weeks of material for employees, there's one slide in the beginning of the presentation that details what they'll go through which I want them to check after each task is done, but to make it easier for and avoid them going back to the first slide after they finish each section, I want to create checkboxes that they tick after finishing each section and for that tick box to reflect on the first slide. I'm doing this using Adobe Acrobat Pro so I guess JS is the way to go.

Thank you for going through all this.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: Nothing yet, I'm unable to find a solution that's why I was hoping someone would help me out.